# updating data via PATCH API in c#

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2013, patch

I need to make a Patch request from a console application (doesn't matter but I assume this would do the job) of the form

```
PATCH '{
  "Fields": [
    {
      "fieldType" : "FName",
      "value" : "ABC123"
    },
    {
      "fieldType" : "LName",
      "value" : "XYZ123",
    },
  ]
}' /api/clients/clientID/Fields/
```

Now, as someone who has knowingly sent only API requests from stuff like Rainmeter, having to do a PATCH request, I honestly am not sure what to do.

```
private string getJsonContent(DataRow _dataRow)
{
    string sb = "PATCH '{\n \"Fields\" : [\n { \"fieldType\" : \"FName\",\n\"value\" : \"" + _dataRow[0].ToString() + "\"\n},\n" +
       "{ \"FieldType\" : \"LName\",\n\"value\" : \"" + _dataRow[1].ToString() + "\"\n}\n]\n}' /api/clients/clientID/Fields/";
    return sb;
}

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//Populate this DataTable using connection to database
}
Uri MyUri = new Uri("http://www.default.com/");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(MyUri);
//request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = accessToken;
request.Method = "PATCH";
request.ContentType = "application/json";

System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    // Send the data.
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();


foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    string data = getJsonContent(dr);
```

**//Now what do I do?**

Nearly everything I can find is about POST/PUT/GET. I can't seem to find any complete sources /  examples of a full patch request. Youtubing about this gives me only results for PUT/POST/GET, stack-overflow seems to have only partial examples about patch, RFC documentation is really hard for me to parse at my level and googling about it isn't yielding much.

Please help ..

Comment: What is this actually yielding as a result?  Are you getting a response?  Do you control the API?

Comment: Due to changes  in  architecture, need to update data  on a service that I partner with. Want to match the data on my database and that service. Fixed the data on my db, now want to also fix the same data on that service too. To do that, they told me to update the data using their PATCH API, to change each of the records on  their database. If its a success, I should get a 200 response.